# How do I write a script/code to stop the apache kafka consumer from consuming the messages?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to write a Java Code in order to start the kafka consumer from consuming the messages. Once the consumer is started from the command line.  But not sure about the standard way to stop the consumer from processing.

In my local windows machine, I have written simple standalone producer and consumer. Now do I stop the standalone consumer from further processing using different code/script.
`   private static final String TOPIC = "conftest";
    private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS =
            "localhost:9092";

```
private static Consumer<String, String> createConsumer() {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"test-consumer-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    // Create the consumer using props.
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    // Subscribe to the topic.
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
    return consumer;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    runConsumer();
}

private static void runConsumer(){
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = createConsumer();
    try{
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumerRecords) {
                System.out.printf("partition = %d, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value()); 
            }
            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
    }catch(WakeupException wue){
        System.out.println("Wake Up Exception Occured");
        wue.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}`
```

Comment: No not to start. But to stop the consumer which is started.

Comment: I have written a standalone java producer to start. My question is how do I stop that using a different Java process.

Comment: can you post the code here it's not clear for me sorry

Comment: Above the sample standalone code I used to start the consumer in Eclipse.

Comment: are you looking for `close()` method, that is only the way to stop consumer

Answer (score 1):

Use `close` method to close the `KafkaConsumer` Just call `consumer.close();`

**public void close()**

> Close the consumer, waiting for up to the default timeout of 30 seconds for any needed cleanup. If auto-commit is enabled, this will commit the current offsets if possible within the default timeout. See close(long, TimeUnit) for details. Note that wakeup() cannot be used to interrupt close.

**public void close(long timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit timeUnit)** With specified time

> Tries to close the consumer cleanly within the specified timeout. This method waits up to timeout for the consumer to complete pending commits and leave the group. If auto-commit is enabled, this will commit the current offsets if possible within the timeout. If the consumer is unable to complete offset commits and gracefully leave the group before the timeout expires, the consumer is force closed. Note that wakeup() cannot be used to interrupt close.